# How to count character followed by Special Character in string using Javascript

Tags: javascript

My string is: `Hello 1⃣2⃣3⃣ world`.
The expected result is `3 (1⃣ 2⃣ and 3⃣)`

Matching condition has total 12 value below:

`(0⃣ 1⃣ 2⃣ 3⃣ 4⃣ 5⃣ 6⃣ 7⃣ 8⃣ 9⃣ *⃣ #⃣ )`

How to use javascript to count total of result? Thank you.

```
// Get code of emoji
function getEmojiUnicode(emoji) {
    var comp;
    if (emoji.length === 1) {
        comp = emoji.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    comp = (
        (emoji.charCodeAt(0) - 0xD800) * 0x400
      + (emoji.charCodeAt(1) - 0xDC00) + 0x10000
    );
    if (comp < 0) {
        comp = emoji.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    return comp.toString("16");
};

// count how many times emoji appears
function countSpecialCharacter(string) {
    // what should I write here?

    return result;
}

var inputString = 'Hello 1⃣2⃣3⃣ world';
var output = countSpecialCharacter(inputString); // this should be 3
```

Definition of Combining Enclosing Keycap is here

https://emojipedia.org/combining-enclosing-keycap/

Comment: Your question is hard to read and understand. What are you trying to do? What do you mean by keycap?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I edited my question, please take a look again.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Or just interested in solutions? `How to use javascript to count total of result`. Javascript has this inherited property `.length`.

Comment: @GetSet I have source code, but it's just simple like that. Input is a string and output is total count of that special character.

Comment: Post your source. Thats why you are getting downvoted.

Comment: @GetSet sorry for that mistake. I uploaded source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Split the string by ' ' and get the words

2) Check each word if it had enclosing keyCap

3) If so, return length/2 (because each char has one enclose)

```js
const count = line => {
  const valid_chars = Array.from("0123456789*#");
  const sp_chars = line.split(" ").find(x => x.includes("⃣"));
  if (sp_chars && sp_chars.length % 2 === 0) {
    return Array.from(sp_chars).filter(x => valid_chars.includes(x)).length;
  }
  return 0;
};

console.log(count("Hello 1⃣2⃣3⃣-⃣ world"));
```

Comment: Something to note: the 'keycap' characters are not the 'keycap' followed by the number, they are one character: 3⃣, you need to search for these, not the 'keycap' character itself as there technically is none in these characters.

Comment: My condition contains only 12 keycap. If input is 1⃣2⃣3⃣-⃣ so the result need to be 3. But your program returns 4. Can you modify your program once again. Thank you.

Comment: @ĐứcNguyễnViệt, Oh right. I just updated to check allowed chars. it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is iterate through each character you have in your string, looking at the unicode character. Once you have this you can compare this to a list of unicode characters you know are 'Keycaps' - giving you the count.

I.e (this is just checking the first character in a string as an example):

```
function isCharacterAKeycap(str) {
    var keycapUnicodeValues = [8000, 8001, 8002];
    return keycapUnicodeValues.includes(str.charCodeAt[0]);
}

str = "1⃣";
isCharacterAKeycap(str);
```